# Meteor ReactJs and 3rd party js library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, external

I study Meteor with React. I don't how to do the following:
I have 3rd party js library (it is not react or meteor ). Library drawing charts and receive data doing http request ( expecting http response as json type ).

Question

- how can I integrate this js library in my meteor + reactjs project to render on the page?
- how should I organize meteor server to response on http request coming from this library

Thanks
Oleg

Comment: Does it come as an npm module? Does it conform to one of the javascript module interfaces? If it is an npm module it's as simple as doing an import statement, or if not, perhaps a require.

Comment: No , it is not npm module. We got it from our partners. code is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the code of the 3rd party in the client folder, so it will be compiled into your app.

Then inside the component using this 3rd party, if the 3rd library requires initialization you should put the init code inside `componentDidMount` function. You should also keep a reference to the 3rd instance, if it requires further interactions:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.3rdCodeRef = 3rdCode.init();
  }
  render() {
    //...
  }
}
```